# nodejs mysql design pattern for function - conditional statement with iteration, change the values

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, design-patterns, node-mysql

I have two node mysql statements to retrieve data.

```
//one query
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
connection.query('select * from tablejohn' , function(err, rows, fields) {  
infoCleanup(rows,"rows[i]");
} });


//2 queries (multiqueries in one statement)
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
connection.query('select count(*)  as Companycount from tablejohn WHERE elif in (3,4);select * FROM tablejohn WHERE  elif in (3,4)', function(err, rows, fields) {
infoCleanup(rows,"rows[1][i]");
} });
```

to iterate and change the values I've created a function for this

```
var infoCleanup = function(rows,type){

if (type=="rows[i]"){
//iterate and change the value
for(var i=0;i<rows.length; i++)
rows[i].a = toTittleCase(rows[i].a);
rows[i].b = toTittleCase(rows[i].b);
rows[i].c = toTittleCase(rows[i].c);
}

else if(type=="rows[1][i]"){
//iterate and change the value
for(var i=0;i<rows[1].length; i++)
rows[1][i].a = toTittleCase(rows[1][i].a);
rows[1][i].b = toTittleCase(rows[1][i].b);
rows[1][i].c = toTittleCase(rows[1][i].c);
}

}
```

For now I have been using the above infoCleanup(rows,type) function and from there set a conditional statement.

The question how can I improve my infoCleanUp function for a better maintainable code (i.e design pattern ,oop etc)?

As you can see the execute statement( "iterate and change the value") for both conditional do the same things, only different is
either variable rows[i] or  variable rows[1][i] . So I guess we dont have conditional statement in this case and reduce line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is too local piece of code to apply some OOP patterns to it.
I would just decompose it into functions:

```js
// Test data
data_rows = [
  {a: 'test', 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'},
  {a: 'test_two', 'b': 'b_two', 'c': 'c_two'}
];

data_rows1 = [
  [],
  [
    {a: 'test', 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'},
    {a: 'test_two', 'b': 'b_two', 'c': 'c_two'}
  ]
];

// Convert function
var convertTitle = function(row) {
  row.a = row.a.toUpperCase();
  row.b = row.b.toUpperCase();
  row.c = row.c.toUpperCase();
}

// Cleanup loop
var infoCleanup = function(rows, getter) {
  for(var i=0;i<rows.length; i++) {
      convertTitle(getter(rows, i));
  }
}

// The anonymous function captures the difference (rows[i] vs rows[1][i])
infoCleanup(data_rows, function(rows, i) { return rows[i]; } );
alert(JSON.stringify(data_rows));


infoCleanup(data_rows1, function(rows, i) { return rows[1][i]; } );
alert(JSON.stringify(data_rows1));
```

Comment: thanks @Boris. Looks good. Just to confirm on this line convertTitle(getter(rows, i));  What thats getter? argument inside argument ?

Comment: @Fairul see how the `infoCleanup` is called, getter is a function passed as a second argument. So this is the argument-function.